# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, maven, liquibase

У меня есть приложение Spring, в проекте 2 модуля core и migration, я использую testcontainer для интеграционных тестов и хочу чтобы миграция сама накатывалась через liquibase, все работает только в том случае если все файлы миграции лежат в модуле core в папке resourse, но мне надо чтобы все файлы связанные с liquibase лежали в модуле migrationю

application.properties (в модуле core) я добавляю вот эти проперти

```
...
spring.liquibase.change-log=/../../../../migration/src/main/resources/db/master.xml
spring.liquibase.contexts=test
```

Но почему то я получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
The file /../../../../migration/src/main/resources/db/master.xml 
was not found in - Spring resources
```

Путь этот правильный, в idea я могу по нему перейти к файлу. Так же модуль migration никаких классов не имеет, там лежит только pom, liquibase.properties, changelog и master.xml.
Зависимость на модуль migration я прописал в pom кора.
Путь к файлу я пробовал через classpath: и classpath*:

Уже все перепробовал, но не понимаю почему когда файлы миграции в отдельном модуле, ничего не работает

Comment: путь до файла надо относительно корня приложения указывать, либо в виде `classpath:db/master.xml` и должно взлететь. вот пример из документации https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/springboot.html

Comment: @zolt боже, спасибо, я чуть не умер пока искал в чем проблема. Я почему то думал, что в доке указано classpath:db/master.xml потому что у них  в ресурсах такой путь

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете IDEA, то убедитесь что вы создали папки db и в ней папку changelog, а не одну папку с названием db.changelog